# Download/read image directly from image url

Tags: karate

Code sample for testing

```
Feature: Photo Download Test
Background:
    * configure continueOnStepFailure = true
    * configure followRedirects = false

  Scenario:
    # initial request to capture random photo
    * url 'https://source.unsplash.com'
    Given path 'user/c_v_r/100x100'
    When method GET
    Then status 302
    * def imageFilePath = karate.response.header('Location')
    * print 'imageFilePath-',imageFilePath

    * def photoName = imageFilePath.split('?')[0].split('/')[3]
    * print 'photoName-',photoName

    * def imageType = imageFilePath.split('?')[1].split('&')[3].split('=')[1]
    * print 'imageType-',imageType

    * def fileName = photoName + '.' + imageType
    * def contentType = 'image/' + imageType

    # image file capture attempts
    * def image = read(imageFilePath)
    * def image = read('file:'+imageFilePath)
    * def image = karate.read('file:'+imageFilePath)
    * print 'image-',image

    # 200 that contains no response value
    * url imageFilePath
    Given path ''
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * def image = response
```

We are looking to download photos from a direct url, but the final response simply returns a 200, with no payload

```
11:17:16.494 [com.intuit.karate.Main.main()] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 8281
2 < 200
2 < Connection: keep-alive
2 < Content-Length: 3576
2 < last-modified: Wed, 21 Feb 2024 18:17:16 GMT
2 < cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
2 < x-imgix-id: 865a9f7e088d398a398951413abaddd4d059a862
2 < Server: Google Frontend
2 < X-Imgix-Render-Farm: 02.66056
2 < Date: Wed, 21 Feb 2024 18:17:16 GMT
2 < Age: 0
2 < Accept-Ranges: bytes
2 < Content-Type: image/jpeg
2 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
2 < Timing-Allow-Origin: *
2 < Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
2 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2 < X-Served-By: cache-sjc1000139-SJC, cache-dfw-kdfw8210069-DFW
2 < X-Cache: MISS, MISS
```

If we back up from here, we can capture the url for the previoous redirected (302) request, but when trying to assign or read the image directly from the url, the relative path is also included in the search, so the result is a file not found.  Even stating file, with the url results in a file not found error as well - see below

**Is there a way to simply download the image to the target folder for later use with a simple read('target/filename.ext')?**

I have tried numerous options, but appear to be missing something

```
01: read(imageFilePath)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /localfilepath for test feature/https:/images.unsplash.com/photo-1608231975456-2f2d9fb1b49b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwODU0MTgyNQ&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=100 (No such file or directory)

01: read('file:'+imageFilePath)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597428963794-aba7182f3abf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwODU0MTc4MA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=100

01: karate.read('file:'+imageFilePath)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597431842922-d9686a23baa6?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwODU0MTQ5OQ&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not working for you because you are using read which expects a file or file path but you are passing a URL from the location header in the redirect.

Here is a working example of how to achieve what you need. I used the redirect location URL from your example for this.

```
Scenario: Download image to target and read it test
  #make request to api which returns an image/jpeg
  Given url "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597428963794-aba7182f3abf?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=100&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTcwODU0MTc4MA&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=100"
  When method get
  Then status 200
  #the response is what holds the image, use karate.write to write it to target folder 
  #writes the bytes of object to a path which will always be relative to the "build" directory (typically target)
  Then karate.write(response, 'testing.jpg')
  #read back the image to a var and do what you need with it
  * def testImage = read('file:' + 'target/testing.jpg')
```

[Karate.write() documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme-ov-file#karate-write)